# How to update many db setting values in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-7

1.I have checkboxes data from view.

```
$data =["name1" =>"value1","name2"=>"value2","name3"=>"value3"]
```

2.I need to update a model in controller something like:

```
Config::update(
          ['id'=>1,"name"=>"name1","value"=>"value1"],
          ['id'=>2,"name"=>"name2","value"=>"value2"],
          ['id'=>3,"name"=>"name2","value"=>"value3"],
       );
```

Comment: what are you trying to actually update? the config values? you can only change them at run time like this, they wont persist since they are files ... are you updating a model named Config?

Comment: yes Im updating a model named config

Comment: Please try your code and let us know when you get an error

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can just iterate through the array of inputs, find the record matching the current id, then update that model instance.

```
foreach ($data as $record) {
    // can we find a model with that id
    if ($model = Config::find($record['id'])) {
        // update that model
        $model->update($record);
    }
}
```